# Appium for Mac OS: Is there a way to send the Enter key properly in the Messages app?

Tags: java, macos, selenium, appium

I'm implementing a framework that makes use of Appium for Mac, to test native MacOS apps. I'm having difficulty performing a simple command of sending the Enter key in the Messages app, which is needed to be able to send a message. To simulate this, I'm using the Selenium method call sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).

Here's what I've tried.

- sendKeys(Keys.RETURN) does the same thing.
- Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform()
- I tried creating the WebDriver as an IOSDriver to see if it was maybe a casting issue, also to no avail.
- Using the Robot class is not what we need because our code needs to be able to run even when the workstation is locked.
- I tried concatenating the ENTER key to the message I'm trying to send, also to no avail.
- When trying to press the ENTER key in the Activity Monitor, the same symbol does NOT show up; it only does so in Messages. I suspect it may have something to do with the encoding?

```
        WebElement webElement = appiumForMacDriver.findElement(ELEMENT_LOCATOR);

        appiumForMacDriver.sendKeys(webElement, message);
        appiumForMacDriver.sendKeys(webElement, Keys.ENTER);
```

Instead of actually sending the message, however, it simply enters this symbol: 

It looks like Appium for Mac is very preliminary and doesn't support a lot of basic features. Is there a step or workaround I could take to be actually able to submit the Enter key?

Comment: I am experiencing similar behavior where when I try to send the ENTER key I'm getting:

`Could not find selector (post_actions:data:) for path '/session/dpQ4H8XA/actions'.`

Answer (score 0):

Import `actionchains` and try something like below:

```java
WebElement webElement = appiumForMacDriver.findElement(ELEMENT_LOCATOR);
ActionChains(appiumForMacDriver).move_to_element(webElement).click().perform()
Actionchains(appiumForMacDriver).sendKeys(message).perform();
```